# Player "sliding" after a collision for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 2D platformer, I also have an event that occurs that when my player collides with a specific trigger it supposed to stop moving. For the most time that works fine...however, when i am walking the sprite collides...my character keeps sliding and I cant figure out why.

There is a boxCollider 2D marked as a trigger on my player along with a Kinematic Rigidbody2D and a Circle Collider 2D with a Dynamic Rigidbody2D on the sprite which comes in contact with my player.

```cs
public class MyCharacterControls : MonoBehaviour {

  //public GameObject player;
  //Get the Character
    public Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;
    public bool Stunned;
    public float StunnedFor = 5.0f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Stunned)
        {
            //  HandleStun();
            _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            _rigidbody.angularVelocity = 0;
            StartCoroutine(HandleStun());     
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator HandleStun()
    {
        //Stunned, De activate movement  
        CharacterHorizontalMovement moveScript = GetComponent<CharacterHorizontalMovement>();
        CharacterJump jumpScript = GetComponent<CharacterJump>();
        jumpScript.AbilityPermitted = false;
        moveScript.AbilityPermitted = false;
        _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        _rigidbody.angularVelocity = 0;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(StunnedFor);
        jumpScript.AbilityPermitted = true;
        moveScript.AbilityPermitted = true;
        Stunned = false;
    }     

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "FallingObject")
        {
            Debug.Log("trigger with fallinng ball");
            Stunned = true;     
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, Ive tried setting velocity and angularVelocity and there is still no stopping of this sliding.

Grateful if anyone could assist.

Regards

[image: Ball]
[image: Player]

Comment: Can you upload screenshot of the Rigidbody2D settings?

Comment: I've added the ball and the player to the screenshot

Comment: The problem is not from the code you posted. You have another code is that is secretly modifying the object.  It could be `CharacterHorizontalMovement`, `CharacterJump` or `CorgiController`. You can easily find out by disabling each one one by one until it stops sliding.

Comment: Something that can override the modifying of the velocity in the update? ok i will look.

Comment: Does it keep sliding infinitely? or does it eventually grind to a halt? You may be able to solve this by adding a physics material to the player using a higher friction (the default for unity is 0.4 i believe).https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html

Comment: It slides for the duration of the stun, even if changing the material can "fix" it, I want to see why that's occurring rather than doing a work around

Comment: Did you figure out? I have the same problem.

Comment: @MehmetEminAcar Whoa, I might have but, that was so long ago, I dont even know what project I was working on. What I think happened was, I think at that time I purchased Corgi 2D engine, and there was a function that paused the player. I think I just called that.